# jQuery append new key value pair to existing data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

Is this possible, my div data attribute is:

```
data-obj="{"__type":"GalleryImgModel","GalleryImageId":49,"GalleryId":0,"PersonId":264}"
```

and the jquery I tried based on the docs  (Ive already defined item correctly!)

```
item.data('obj',{"MoreThanOneImage" : moreThanOneImage});
```

Help would be great thanks

Comment: the `data-obj` attribute value is not correct as the string enclosing quotes are messing with quotes of json attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the data attribute string to an object first, then add the value(s). Try something like:

```
$('#my-element').data($.extend({'new-key':'new-value'},
    JSON.parse($('#my-element').data()));
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I used $.extend(item.data('obj'), { "MoreThanOneImage": moreThanOneImage }) and it worked fine

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped! Normally I'd say to be careful with the order of your arguments to `$.extend` and to remember that it's mutating state in-place -- but here it doesn't really make a difference.